# Dynamic Post Data Values for Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, database, dynamic

On my page I have multiple dropdowns like so:

```
<select class="form-control extra-dropdown" id="extra-1" name="extra[1]">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control extra-dropdown" id="extra-2" name="extra[2]">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control extra-dropdown" id="extra-3" name="extra[3]">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
```

These dropdowns are created dynamically - depending on where the user has come from determines what and how many dropdowns are shown.

When the user changes any of these options I want to run a php script with jQuery.ajax and it needs all the selected values for extra[]. SO it would be like so:

```
$('select.extra-dropdown').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'my-ajax-script.php',
        data: { 
            postVar1: $('#extra-1').val(), 
            postVar2: $('#extra-2').val(),
            postVar3: $('#extra-3').val()
        },
        beforeSend:function(){
            // show loader...
        },
        success:function(data){
            // show xxx...
        },
        error:function(){
            // show errors...
        }
    });
});
```

However how do I populate the `data: {}` dynicamlly based on how many dropdown options are on the page. It can vary from 1 on the page to a max of 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
var dataOut = [];
$.each($('.extra-dropdown'),function(index,value){
    dataOut['extra-'+index] = $(this).val();
    //or 
    //dataOut[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();       
});
```

Then

```
data : dataOut
```

Comment: Thank you that works. What would I use to get the extras in my php script? (for example I want to access them in a loop liek so: `foreach ($_POST['extra'] as $id => $value) { ...}`

Comment: if im not mistaken you could always just send the array and traverse it in php. try `data : { 'extraArray' : dataOut}` then in php do `foreach ($_POST['extraArray']`